# Can I filter elements in smart component by props params from store in Redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux

To my smart component ("lists") I to pass the "list_id" property. Also, I have "tasks" in a store. I want filter "tasks" from store in connect method by "list_id".
For example: `tasks:state.tasks.filter(task => task.task_list_id == this.props.list_id)`. But it's not work for me. How I can filter elements from store by props params? (I don't change store).
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of filtering based on props. Why not set the filter in the redux store giving you easy access to it in your connect function
?

Comment: Ok. My structure is: boards-lists-tasks for this list. Yes, I can save current clicked board object in store. Ok, I save also lists for this board. But how I can showing tasks for this list in loop? (Aka Trello app)

Comment: Show more code and I can get a better idea of what you need to do. You can use map on the tasks to return component that will display the tasks in the render. This is different from your original question though?

Comment: My idea is: I load all "tasks" objects in Store when app is loading. And then i simple filtering this tasks objects for a different areas ( "to do list"  or "important" list or "Done" list). Of course I may load it from API (for each list) but I understand that "tasks" - this is a single essence and it can save in Store. May be I not right? Thanks.